# How to set the font for the page numbers separately to the headings in a table of contents?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016

The page numbers in a tables of content will use the same font as the heading. Is it possible to assign a style to the page numbers separately? So far, the solution seems to be to highlight all the page numbers and set it that way.

Comment: Welcome to SU! Based on [this Office tutorial](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/format-or-customize-a-table-of-contents-9d85eb9c-0b55-4795-8abb-a49885b3a58d), it doesn't look like there exists a nice, user-facing way to do what you're looking for :( You could probably write a VBA script/macro to do the selecting-and-font-changing automatically, though. Is that something you'd be interested in?

Comment: That works too.